# ajax JavaScriptにfor文を埋め込みたい

Tags: jquery, ajax

下記の様な書き方は可能でしょうか？
doneのsearchResultでの結果を数分回したいのですが、どのように書けばいいのかわかりません。
上記で実行してみた結果ループは動きませんでした。ajaxの結果をどのように回すのか教えていただきたいです。

---

Ajax

```
$(function(){
    $('#ajax').on('click',function(){

        $.ajax({
            url:'/home',
            type:'GET',
            data:{

            }
        })
        .done( (searchResult) => {

            $('result').html(searchResult);
            console.log(searchResult);   console.log(searchResult);

            var total=searchResult;
            for(total i=0; i < 'searchResult';i++){
            $('.result').append('<tr><td>' + testingDateFrom + '</td><td>' + testingDateTo + '</td><td>' + competitionName + '</td><td>' + kitSendPrefecture + '</td><td>' + associationName + '</td><td>' + subAssociationName + '</td></tr>')
            }
        })
```

Comment: searchResult　にはどのようなデータが帰ってきますか？例で結構ですので、追記いただけると幸いです。

Comment: ｛2013,2019,東北地区、関東地区、ランニング、体育会｝
このようなデータなのですが、大丈夫でしょうか？

Comment: 一行だけってことですか？console.logで吐き出されているデータをいただければ問題ないのですが、

Comment: ｛2013,2019,東北地区、関東地区、ランニング、体育会｝｛2017,2022,関東地区、関西地区、水泳、競技会｝こちらが表示したいデータです。

Comment: 申し訳ないですが、その書き方だとデータの集まりが配列なのか、オブジェクトなのかわからないです。どちらかわかるように書いてもらってもよろしいですか？

Comment: すいませんでした。。以下でだいじょうぶでしょうか？
var hoge = [ ‘2013’ , ‘2019’ , ‘東北地区’,‘ランニング’ , ‘体育会’],[ ‘2017’ , ‘2022’ , ‘関東地区’,‘水泳’ , ‘競技会’];

Comment: 申し訳ないです、頂いたソースだとJavascriptのエラーが出てしまいます。

Comment: for(total i=0; i < 'searchResult';i++)のせいでしょうか？

Comment: 「console.log(searchResult)」の結果が「var hoge=[ '2013', ... 」なのでしょうか?

Comment: いえエラーが出るのは  `var hoge = [ ‘2013’ , ‘2019’ , ‘東北地区’,‘ランニング’ , ‘体育会’],[ ‘2017’ , ‘2022’ , ‘関東地区’,‘水泳’ , ‘競技会’];` の部分です。